# Sliding on a plane

Tags: math, game-physics

I have a plane (Point, normal) and a circle(point, radius).
The circle moves around and hits the plane.
The position of the circle is reset to the touchPoint with the plane.
So far, so good.
But how can i modify the velocity of the circle, so it only moves
tangential to the plane?

So if it bumbs in the plane, the part of the velocity-vector which is
responsible for bumbing in the plane is consumed. 
So, in the next step, it doesnt collide with the plane but can move on.

It "slides" on the plane.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is a little confusing. You mention a plane, so you apparently are dealing with 3D Cartesian space. But in such a space, a circle needs more than `(point, radius)` to define it. It also needs a specification of a plane through the radius. What is your full definition of the circle? Also, just how is the circle moving at the time of impact with the plane. Is the orientation of the circle fixed? Just how is the velocity of the circle represented: by a Cartesian velocity vector? Please clarify with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you give no code, I'll just state a few ideas without code.

The plane's definition of `(Point, normal)` is simpler if the normal vector is a unit vector (of length one). If it isn't, divide that vector by its length and it becomes a unit vector.

If the velocity of the circle is is given by a 3D Cartesian velocity vector, you can find the component of that velocity vector along the plane's unit normal vector by taking the dot product of those two vectors. The result is the directed size of the vector along the normal. You can then remove that component by multiplying the unit normal vector by that dot product, then subtracting that from the circle's velocity vector. The result of that subtraction is the circle's velocity along the plane. That apparently is what you wanted to find.

If you answer my questions in my comment under your question, I could show you some code in my current preferred language, Python 3.

Comment: thank you Rory. Yes, it's the solution. Code is not necessary.